# Sharepoint 2013 list views with common buttons menu bar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a list with multiple views (around 15 views). How can I add a same set of buttons to all the views below the page title and above list web part? I have SharePoint designer. I have used content editor web part, but I need to add it to all view aspx pages and add the same set of buttons.
Any better solutions?

Thanks
Venky

Answer (score 0):

You could read the existing views with javascript (JSOM) to retrieve all the existing views on the specified list.

In the `OnQuerySucceed` function while looping through the views you could generate a button and add it the DOM. For example in your content editor add a  element and push the buttons in their.

```
var viewCollection = null;

function runCode() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
    var web = clientContext.get_web();

    var listCollection = web.get_lists();
    var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Tasks");
    this.viewCollection = list.get_views();

    var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
    viewInfo.set_title('MyView');
    this.viewCollection.add(viewInfo);

    clientContext.load(this.viewCollection);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var viewInfo = 'Tasks list current views: \n\n';
    var viewEnumerator = this.viewCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
        viewInfo += view.get_title() + '\n';
    }
    alert(viewInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```